# How to revert a chunk of a file in the staging area?

Tags: git

I have a file in my staging area and I want to unstage a chunk of it.
I know I can use the following command:

```
 git reset --patch -- <my_file>
```

But in my case, the name file was renamed and every time I am trying to validate the reset, I have the following error:

> fatal: new file my_file depends on old contents

Is there a way to do what I need? Or I am screwed?

#### Edit:

I read the following documentation before posting this question:

- [Undo local changes interactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295986/undo-local-changes-interactive/23296148#23296148)
- http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging
- http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified

#### Edit:

Git status output:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        renamed:    src/MyBundle/Config.php -> src/MyBundle/QueryConfig/Config.php
```

In the rename process, I want to keep some changes (namespace change) but I want to discard other changes (not related to namespace change) to commit them later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So finally I found a process that works for me:

1. I move the file back to its original location
2. I revert the chunks I don't want to include in the commit
3. I move the file to its final location

So here are the commands :

```
git mv <final_path>/<file> <original_path>/<file>
git reset -p <original_path>/<file>
git mv <original_path>/<file> <final_path>/<file>
```

@MatzZze Even if I did not use your solution, I thank you for your help. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To unstage chunks use:

```
git reset HEAD -p <filename>
```

After that you can reset your changes with

```
git checkout -p <path to file>
```

Comment: It returns me the following error ```error: unknown option `staged'```. My git version is 2.1.4. Is this option only available on later versions of git?

Comment: It is available in 2.x for sure

Comment: I tried that and it is not working. During the ```reset```, I have to reset all the changes since Git thinks that I changed the file. If I am trying to edit the patch, I have error ```warning: recount: unexpected line: <?php

fatal: corrupt patch at line 7```. If I don't edit the patch, it just reset the whole file and the use of ```checkout``` tells me there is no change. :(

Comment: Could you please post the result of git status?

Comment: @MatzZze I edited my post to show you an example of ```git status``` output. I have more changes pending but they are all similar.

Comment: In this case you should reverse the order: 1. Reset all changes. 2. Add the chunks with git add -p 3. Use the git mv command to rename the file